# Fragment+RecyclerView shared enlemnt transition first view weird

Tags: android

https://www.facebook.com/petter.jasa.1/videos/284862310770268/

how to fixed the first one
[image]

I have searched some ways about, it tooks me one day, but I can't fixed, seems all right, but I don't know, any way I'm confused!

there are 4 itemes in recyclerview, but only the first one has some weird,somebody knows what happened,thanks for your help